# Registering my app's mime-type / etc

Tags: mime-types, email-attachments, info.plist

After checking several questions, following many online tutorials, I still cannot get my app to register for my mime-type. I feel like there must be some magic here that I am yet not aware of. Are there any additional steps outside of doctoring my plist file? Or did I doctor this wrong?

The only thing I feel may be an extra issue is that I have changed my project name and maybe there is something not lining up with the build settings and/or provisioning profile? It archives and I am able to install for ad-hoc distribution, I just can't get a file in an email to register with the app.

The file is JSON data that I used NSJSONSerialization to prepare.

Here is my plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
            <string>English</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>ClickDesigner</string>
        <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                <string>Clicker Data Document</string>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
                <string>Owner</string>
                <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>com.digitaldownbeat.clicker.clk</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
        <string>icon.png</string>
        <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
                <array>
                    <string></string>
                    <string>icon.png</string>
                    <string>icon@2x.png</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.digitaldownbeat.${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>Clicker</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>db-k6rrg6wgwv4uij1</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                <string>com.digitaldownbeat.clickdesigner</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>clickdesigner</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>LSRequiresiPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
        <string>MainWindow</string>
        <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
        <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent</string>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
                <array>
                    <string>public.text</string>
                </array>
                <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
                <string>ClickDesigner Data Document</string>
                <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
                <string>com.digitaldownbeat.clickdesigner.clk</string>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>clk</string>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <string>application/clickdesigner</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code into your app's delegate.m file.  Under the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

  NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {}
}
```

This worked for me with audio attachments but I am having problems with my image files.  jpg,png,tif, etc.